# Terminal opens on different manchine when trying to login from xrdp

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

I am trying to login remote to my office machine which is ubuntu 18.04. I am using xrdp. When i Login and click on either "Terminal Emulator" or on "Open In Terminal". The terminal opens on my office machine instead of my laptop. Does anyone know how to fix this?.

Comment: Is this `gnome-terminal`? is there an instance already running on the remote machine? If so, perhaps the issue is related to this: [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I had to download xfce4-terminal to fix this problem.